# Check if hour range is not in 'lunch break' hour range in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, join, time

I want to get offices that are available.

Lets example I rent a car and I want to know the office is open at pickup/dropoff time.

I want to find the offices that open in after `open_time` and before `end_time`.

Office table;

```
+---+-----------+
|id |office_name|
+---+-----------+
|116|  AAAAA    |
|117|  BBBBB    |
|118|  CCCCC    |
|119|  DDDDD    |    
|120|  EEEEE    |     
|121|  FFFFF    |
|122|  GGGGG    |
+---+-----------+
```

Workhour table;

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
|id  |office_id|day_of_week|open_time|close_time|
|1325|116      |4          |09:00:00 |12:00:00  | <- 116 has 1 break (available)
|1326|116      |4          |13:00:00 |18:00:00  |  
|1327|117      |4          |09:00:00 |18:00:00  | <- 117 has no break (available)
|1328|118      |4          |09:00:00 |12:00:00  | <- 118 has 3 break (available)
|1329|118      |4          |13:00:00 |15:00:00  | 
|1330|118      |4          |17:00:00 |20:00:00  | 
|1331|119      |4          |09:00:00 |13:30:00  | <- not available
|1332|220      |4          |15:00:00 |17:30:00  | <- not available
|1332|221      |4          |06:00:00 |17:30:00  | <- not available
|1332|222      |4          |09:00:00 |17:30:00  | <- 222 has no break (available)
+----+------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I can get office when the office has `1` workhour row but I couldn't manage to make a query for
if the office has more than `1` work hour range.

```
SELECT supplier_offices.id          as office_id,
       supplier_offices.supplier_id as supplier_id,
       supplier_offices.name        as supplier_office_label,
FROM "supplier_offices"
         INNER JOIN office_locations on supplier_offices.id = office_locations.supplier_office_id
         INNER JOIN supplier_office_work_hours as wh on supplier_offices.id = wh.supplier_office_id
  AND (supplier_offices.status = true)
  AND ("office_locations"."location_id" IN (3027))
  AND (wh.day_of_week = 4)
  AND (wh.open_time <= '09:01'::time)
  AND ('14:00'::time <= wh.close_time)
```

I got:

```
+---+-----------+
|id |office_name|
+---+-----------+
|119|  DDDDD    | <- 119 has no break    
+---+-----------+
```

Expected:

All offices are available between `09:01` - `14:00`

```
+---+-----------+
|id |office_name|
+---+-----------+
|116|  AAAAA    |
|117|  BBBBB    |
|118|  CCCCC    |
|122|  GGGGG    |
+---+-----------+
```

Comment: You have sample data form one table, but your query references two.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added more information about my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is a little skimpy but if I understand you want both sets of hours on a single row. You can convert the time columns to a string and concatenate open/close columns. Then use STRING_AGG.

```
select supplier_office_id
     ,  string_agg(to_char(open_time,'hh24:mi')||'-'||to_char(close_time,'hh24:mi'), ' | ') as hours
 from office
 group by supplier_office_id;
```

Example [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4c0232b23008044e65e94a8a5e1ee134)

If this is not what you are wanting please edit the question to provide fully  explain what you want and include desired output. Ans full table definitions (DDL).

Comment: This is not what I wanted but thank you anyway! I added more information about my question. I want to find available offices in the given hour range.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is imprecisely or even incorrectly described.

Let's assume there is a table `work_hours` with `office_id`, `open_time`, `close_time`. There may be multiple, non-overlapping periods given per `office_id`. There is a given time range: from `start_time` till `end_time`. In the example given `start_time = 09:01`, `end_time = 14:00`.

One can be interested in solving one of (at least) 3 distinct problems:

1. Find an `office_id` such that the period `start_time` - `end_time` is fully included in the `open_time` - `close_time` period.
2. Find an `office_id` such that the period `start_time` - `end_time` overlaps with at least one `open_time` - `close_time` period for this office. Equivalent form: at least one of `start_time`, `end_time` is between one of the `open_time` - `close_time` periods.
3. Find an `office_id` such that both `start_time` and `end_time` falls into any of the `open_time` - `close_time` periods for this office.

The solutions of the problems 1) and 2) are trivial.

The original question suggests it it in fact problem 3) which is to be solved, even though the given "Expected" table does not contain the correct results for the given example data set (e.g. missing `office_id = 221`, which is open from 06:00 till 17:30 without interruption).

Problem 3) boils down to:

1. finding all `office_id` such that `open_time <= start_time <= close_time` --> `t1`
2. finding all `office_id` such that `open_time <= end_time <= close_time` --> `t2`
3. finding an intersection of the above sets --> `t1 INNER JOIN t2`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mentioned that `office_id = 221` should be included in `Expected` table. `office_id = 221` opens at `06:00` which is an early hour than given `open_time` which is `09:01`. When you go to the store at `06:00` the store will not be open. Imagine you want to rent a car and `09:01-17:30` is your pickup/dropoff hours. You can't get there at `06:00`. Office not will be open. I want to find the offices that open in after `open_time` and before `end_time`.

Comment: Now, I'm a bit puzzled about your problem statement.